# How can I query for documents where date is greater than a provided date?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of events that contain the date of the event stored in this format: YYYY-MM-DD. I want to query for all events that are greater than a provided date. This is what I have so far:

```
var eventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title : String,
    details : String,
    start_date : String,
    company: {
        type: String,
        ref: 'Company'
    }
});

eventSchema.methods.getUpcomingEvents = function(company_id, cb) {
var date = utils.dateToday(); // returns e.g., '2015-02-26'

return this.model('Event')
    .find({ company: company_id, start_date : {$gte: date} })
    .sort({start_date: 'asc'})
    .exec(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR = ' + err);
            cb(false, err);
        } else {
            cb(null, data);
        }
    })
};
```

The problem is that this query is return events that occur before the provided 'date'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start_date is String, make it Date if you want to perform date comparisons.

change the schema to something like this;

```
var eventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title : String,
    details : String,
    start_date : Date,
    company: {
        type: String,
        ref: 'Company'
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this while keeping 'start_date' as a String?

Comment: Change it to a date type, it's almost always better.